# The grid-span function don't work with Singularitygs and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

So, first of all I have the following configuration:

- Rails 4.0.2
- Sass 3.2.13
- Compass 0.12.2

And my files are below:

---

**Gemfile**

```ruby
...
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'breakpoint'
gem 'singularitygs'
...
```

---

**application.css.scss**

```sass
/* Mixins */
@import 'compass';
@import 'breakpoint';
@import 'singularitygs';

/* Variables */
$grids: 12;
$gutters: 1/3;

/* Styles */
* { @include box-sizing('border-box'); }

.container {
  @include background-grid;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;

  @include clearfix;
}

header {
  .logo { @include grid-span(4, 1); }
  .user { @include grid-span(4, 8); }
}
```

---

**HTML**

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="user">User</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

The `grid-span` function is returning nothing (blank). This image represents what I expect:

[image: Expect]

And this, what I have:

[image: Reality]

Does anyone have any idea how can I solve it to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the only thing you're missing is the [`Output Style`](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Output-Styles), because of which the `div`s are going to render default which is one stacked on top of other.

Update your `application.css.scss`'s variables section as follows (Not required to be defined here but this is where it would make more sense!, i.e. with `$grids` and `$gutters`):

```
/* Variables */
$grids: 12;
$gutters: 1/3;
$output: 'float';
```

This will set the output style to `float` and your `grid-span` `div`s should `float` as you've shown in your expected result.

Comment: Thanks, but don't work! Firstly, `$output` have a default parameter and it is "isolation". Secondarily, even I wanted set "float" in the global scope, it don't work (although it should). Finally, if I call the function like `@include grid-span(4, 1, $output-style: 'float');` it magically works!

Comment: I haven't tested it but what happens if you define your variables before your include statements?

Comment: I have already tested it, but the results are the same. (I even restarted the Rails thinking it might be related.)

Answer (score 0):

hm if you try your setup on sassmeister it works. the only thing i've changed was:

@include grid-span(4, 8);
to 
@include grid-span(4, 9);
cuz if you start at column 8 you get only to column 11 if your spanned grid is 4 columns wide. but aside that it comes to your expected result:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/8226741

Comment: The asker sais that the `grid-span` function returns no output, so it is some sort of a Rails setup issue.